# Does "Drive Him Back!" also prevent advancement of the monster on this turn?

Tags: castle-panic

Castle Panic's "Drive Him Back" states:

> Play this card and move 1 Monster all the way back into the Forest, keeping it in the same numbered arc.

Does that monster then stay there during the next immediate Phase 5: Move Monsters?  Or does that monster go ahead and move to the archers ring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the rules state that all Monsters move ahead in Phase 5 (and there is nothing specifically stating that this one should not move), I see no reason why it wouldn't move along with all the other monsters. That's how my group has always played.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a card specifically states otherwise you do exactly what is said on it. So in the case of *Drive Him Back* you would move the affected monster forward from the forest to the archer ring on Phase 5.